# How to use DPAPI under load balance environment

Tags: encryption, web-application, key-management, .net

DPAPI can be used to encrypt the secret data. 
We intend to use it in our web app to encrypt some data and store the encrypted data in database. When needed we decrypt the data and present them on UI(web page). It works well if we hosted the web app on a single web server. But the problem appears when we migrate it to a load balance environment -  hosting the web app on multiple web server. Because the app cannot decrypt the data which encrypted on another machine.  
We refer to some information from internet, it looks like we need to config a roaming user account and run the application pool with that account.

The reason we want to use DPAPI is that it will not involve additional management work on the keys.

Do you have some similar experience, how do you solve the problem? Or some other suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

There are two relatively small changes you should make to your setup.

First of all, you should always be using DPAPI in `USER_MODE`, this is a parameter to the DPAPI methods.
(The `.Protect()` methods of `ProtectedData` and `ProtectedMemory` classes take an additional scope parameter, this should be set to `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` for `ProtectedData`, or `MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon` for `ProtectedMemory`, depending on which you are using.)
(If you are calling the WINAPI functions directly, which I hope you're not using, you can send the `USER_MODE` parameter directly too. Oh, and use the .NET classes instead.)

Secondly, you should be using the DPAPI classes to encrypt your encryption key - *not* the data directly.
In other words, you generate a single encryption key, distribute this to all your servers, and have them store the key via DPAPI. (Yes, you'll probably need a small utility for this.)
This will make any key management processes much easier, the key is shared so decryption is easier, and it is still protected by the DPAPI encryption.

Comment: thanks avid, I did use DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser to do the encryption and decription. But I am not quite understand your second point. why I cannot encrypt the data directly, instead just encrypt the encryption key. Is it a normal approach to do the similar things? If encrypt the keys with DPAPI, I will face the same situation which is the app cannot decrypt the encryption key encrypted by another machine. You might have some experience on DPAPI. Is roaming user profile necessary if we want to use DPAPI and the CurrentUser in a load balance environment?

Comment: You dont need the user to be a roaming user, that only affects the location of the user profile storage. In your case, you're saving the encrypted data yourself, after it is encrypted according to the user's account - dont worry about that part. In any event - yes, you should be having a single shared key for encryption, and using DPAPI for protecting the key in storage.

Comment: +1 on the small utility. Too many people stick the key in the app config to do the install and forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

Eight years later . . . you can try using [CNG DPAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-dpapi), which was meant to work in cloud environments that may or may not be load-balanced.  From that link (in case it gets taken down):

> Microsoft introduced the data protection application programming
> interface (DPAPI) in Windows 2000. The API consists of two functions,
> CryptProtectData and CryptUnprotectData. DPAPI is part of CryptoAPI
> and was intended for developers who knew very little about using
> cryptography. The two functions could be used to encrypt and decrypt
> static data on a single computer.
>
> Cloud computing, however, often requires that content encrypted on one
> computer be decrypted on another. Therefore, beginning with Windows 8,
> Microsoft extended the idea of using a relatively straightforward API
> to encompass cloud scenarios. This new API, called DPAPI-NG, enables
> you to securely share secrets (keys, passwords, key material) and
> messages by protecting them to a set of principals that can be used to
> unprotect them on different computers after proper authentication and
> authorization.

In .NET Core this looks like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDataProtection()
        .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG();
}
```

#### Update

I like using Entity Framework (EF) + CNG-DPAPI.  In .NET Core you can create a "Keys" Context using EF.  First add a connection string in your appsettings.json file to a SQL database where you'll store your keys.  In this example, we're calling it "MyKeysConnection."

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyKeysConnection": "Server=XXX;Database=YYY;"
    }
}
```

Next create a class in your project like this:

```
class MyKeysContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    // A recommended constructor overload when using EF Core 
    // with dependency injection.
    public MyKeysContext(DbContextOptions<MyKeysContext> options) 
        : base(options) { }

    // This maps to the table that stores keys.
    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, type `Script-Migration -Context MyKeysContext` to get a script you can run in SSMS that will create the table for you where your keys will be stored.  Lastly update the code in your Startup.cs file that I posted above to look like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add a DbContext to store your Database Keys
    services.AddDbContext<MyKeysContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyKeysConnection")));

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .PersistKeysToDbContext<MyKeysContext>()
        .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG();
}
```

More on this method can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#entity-framework-core).

Comment: Here are further information on [how to call `ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG()` with a parameter to pass an SID or a certificate hash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1#windows-dpapi-ng).